# Entity Framework sql_variant as primary key

Tags: c#, entity-framework, sql-variant

For a project I used EF Core 5.0 to scaffold an existing database.

The database has some tables with `sql_variant` columns as a part of the primary key.

The model created the property as an 'object'.

Base `OnModelCreating` of this property:

```
  entity.Property(e => e.OperationNo)
    .HasColumnType("sql_variant")
    .HasColumnName("Operation No_");
```

When I try to test this auto scaffold I get the error message:

> 'Property 'ProdOrderRoutingLine.OperationNo' cannot be used as a key because it has type 'object' which does not implement 'IComparable', 'IComparable' or 'IStructuralComparable'. Use 'HasConversion' in 'OnModelCreating' to wrap 'object' with a type that can be compared.'

So I have tried a lot of conversion `sql_variant` to string or object or ... with comparer. To make it simple I'll try to convert it to a string which has a default comparer.

```
 entity.Property(e => e.OperationNo)
   .HasColumnType("sql_variant")
   .HasColumnName("Operation No_")
   .HasConversion<string>(str => str.ToString(), sql => sql.ToString());
```

Here I changed my property to `string` if I leave it as an `object` I get the same error:

> 'The property 'ProdOrderRoutingLine.OperationNo' is of type 'string' which is not supported by the current database provider. Either change the property CLR type, or ignore the property using the '[NotMapped]' attribute or by using 'EntityTypeBuilder.Ignore' in 'OnModelCreating'

Any ideas how to overcome this problem and to use the existing `sql_variant` as a partial primary key?

`OnModelCreate` primary key:

```
entity.HasKey(e => new { e.Status, e.ProdOrderNo, e.RoutingReferenceNo, e.RoutingNo, e.OperationNo });
```

part of the Model:

```
public partial class ProdOrderRoutingLine
{
    public byte[] Timestamp { get; set; }
    public int Status { get; set; }
    public string ProdOrderNo { get; set; }
    public int RoutingReferenceNo { get; set; }
    public string RoutingNo { get; set; }
    public object OperationNo { get; set; }
    public string NextOperationNo { get; set; }
    public string PreviousOperationNo { get; set; }
    public int Type { get; set; }
    public string No { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Fix issue like the original error message says.  See : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/value-conversions?tabs=data-annotations

Comment: I have have tried a couple of these ValueConversions already but none seem to work in this case. then I keep on getting the second error message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make the conversions work i had to comment out:

```
.HasColumnType("sql_variant")
```